# History.js - Updating the initial state(first loaded page before push another state)

Tags: javascript, ajax, pushstate, history.js

Sorry for my bad english :(

I tried `History.js` and it works for me, i can push new states and update the content when i use the back/forward browser button but i have a problem with the initial state.

First of all when **the first page** is called i replace the state, initialize it like this:

```
History.replaceState({state: initialDataToStore}, document.title, document.location.href);
```

When i click on a link, i push a state and i update the **div#content** using an ajax request like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.js-nav',function(event) {
    var url = $(this).prop('href');
    History.pushState(state, 'title', url);
    loadContent(state, url);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

When i use the back/forward button, the **'statechange'** event is fired, so i call the loadContent function to update the **div#content** like this:

```
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ 
    var State = History.getState(); 
    url = State.url;
    loadContent(State.data, url);
});
```

That's the **loadContent** function :

```
function loadContent(state, url){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET'
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        $('#content').empty().append(data);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
}
```

I have a problem with the first loaded page if it has already a previous element in the browser history like this:

```
1- new tab or another page
2- first loaded page (that i force the replaceState)
3- ...
```

If i go back to **"new tab or another page"** using the browser back button then i click on the forward button > **"first loaded page"**, i lose all the html **"layout"**(html, scripts, head, body ...), only the ajax response will be displayed(content to append to **div#content**).

**P.S:** 
If i don't have a previous element **"new tab or another page"** on the history my **"first loaded page"** works correctly, i don't lose the Html layout .

What i have to do ?

Thanks

Comment: I try without history.js but have the same problem. With chromium and firefox. Only the ajax response visible without the page from which it was called.